# Is this redux reducer OK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability

Is this reducer OK:

```
function someReducer(state = initialState, action) {
   if (action.type === SOME_ACTION) {
      const newState = Object.assign( {}, state );
      // ...
      // doing whatever I want with newState 
      // ...
      return newState;
   }   
   return state;
}
```

and if is OK, why we need all those immutable libraries to complicate our lives.

p.s
Just trying to comprehend Redux and immutability

Comment: Which part do you have a question with? SO is not for code reviews

Comment: @ristepan I would suggest ask it to [react reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/). You may not get attention on this even though it is a valid good question here. SO has many rules.. Better go and ask to more flexible places like I mentioned.

Comment: ___For deep cloning, we need to use other alternatives because [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone) copies property values. If the source value is a reference to an object, it only copies that reference value.___

Comment: @JuanMendes Question is clear.

Comment: `assign` is not a deep clone, so you could still reach in and directly modify state.

Comment: @ArupRakshit There are multiple solutions, it's a matter of taste. Sorry, but yes SO does have its rules and yes, the existing code is OK as long as the OP doesn't modify sub-objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
export default function (state = initialState, action) {

  const actions = {
    SOME_ACTION: () => {
      return {
        ...state
      }
    },
    ANOTHER_ACTION: () => {
      return {
        ...state
        error: action.error
      }
    },
    DEFAULT: () => state;
  }
  
  return actions[action.type] ? actions[action.type]() : actions.DEFAULT(); 
}
```

I prefer doing this instead. I am not a big fan of switch statements.

Comment: First time seeing this flow.  Tasty!

Comment: Check this out: https://medium.com/chrisburgin/rewriting-javascript-replacing-the-switch-statement-cfff707cf045. It contains more examples and explanations.

Comment: Nice!  Thanks dude.

Comment: I like this, and I'll try it

Comment: Is this correct? As far as I can tell, it does _not_ return a new state, it returns a _function_ of a new state. Also, it recreates the entire `actions` object each time the reducer function runs – would be better to have the `actions` defined _outside_ the reducer.

Comment: The actions are outside of the reducer. The object just replaces the switch statement, the function returns the state itself and by accessing objects with dot notation is far better than having a switch statement.

Comment: @NicolaeMaties Nope, it returns a function, the `actions` constant is defined inside the reducer and contains reducer functions itself which work over closures and preferring objects over switch-case statements is highly subjective.

Comment: You are right, it just needed the call, i edited it.

Answer (score 3):

The standard approach is to use a `switch/case` with spread syntax (`...`) in your reducer.

```
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.SOME_ACTION:
      return {
        ...state,
        newProperty: action.newProperty
      };

    case constants.ERROR_ACTION:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.error
      };

    case constants.MORE_DEEP_ACTION:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: {
          ...state.users,
          user1: action.users.user1
        }
      };

    default:
      return {
        ...state
      }
  }
}
```

You can then use ES6 spread syntax to return your old state with whatever new properties you want changed/added to it.

You can read more about this approach here...
https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator

Comment: Noting that `...` is *also* a shallow clone, and may not be sufficient.

Comment: It is pretty same approach I think, I understand now assign is not complete deep copy.

Comment: Yes, I also added a nested property update to my answer so you can see an example of how to update a nested property.

Answer (score 1):

I found something that I really like:

```
 import createReducer from 'redux-starter-kit';
 const someReducer = createReducer( initialState, {
    SOME_ACTION: (state) => { /* doing whatever I want with this local State */ },
    SOME_ANOTHER_ACTION: (state) => { /* doing whatever I want with local State */ },
    THIRD_ACTION: (state, action) => { ... }, 
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

If your state has nested objects or arrays, `Object.assign` or `...` will copy references to your older state variable and it may cause some issue. This is the reason why some developers use immutable libraries as in most of the case state has deep nested array or objects.

```
function someReducer(state = initialState, action) {
   if (action.type === SOME_ACTION) {
       const newState = Object.assign( {}, state );
       // newState can still have references to your older state values if they are array or orobjects

      return newState;
   }   
   return state;
}
```

Comment: You just copied his question, there is no answer here.

Comment: @rrd I think the embedded comment is intended to be the answer.

Comment: Answers should be obvious, and visible without hscrolling.

Comment: I have now also explained the reason.

Comment: After all I think something like deepassig function will do the job, at least for me. I like the immer  library